# matio can't find HDF5 libraries

Tags: c++, matlab, ubuntu, gcc, hdf5

I'm trying to compile my code on a Ubuntu machine. I run the following code:

```
g++ refine_pascal_v4/dense_inference.cpp -o prog_refine_pascal_v4 -W -Wall -O2 -L. -lDenseCRF -lmatio -I./util/
```

and i get the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to 

`H5P_CLS_FILE_CREATE_g'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5T_NATIVE_SHORT_g'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Pcreate'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Tcopy'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Aget_space'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Sget_simple_extent_dims'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Eset_auto2'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Sget_simple_extent_ndims'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Aget_type'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Fcreate'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Sclose'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Rcreate'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5T_NATIVE_SCHAR_g'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Aopen_name'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Tget_class'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Acreate2'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Aclose'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5T_NATIVE_ULONG_g'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Pset_deflate'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5T_C_S1_g'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Dopen2'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Iget_type'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Dget_type'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5T_NATIVE_FLOAT_g'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Dwrite'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5T_NATIVE_HSIZE_g'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Screate_simple'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Aread'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5check_version'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Iget_name'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Gcreate2'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Tget_size'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Gget_objname_by_idx'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Tvlen_create'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5T_NATIVE_UCHAR_g'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Eget_auto2'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Screate'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Sselect_elements'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Gopen2'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Gget_objtype_by_idx'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Dget_space'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Dclose'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Eprint1'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5T_NATIVE_LONG_g'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Pset_userblock'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Pclose'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5T_NATIVE_UINT_g'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Tinsert'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Rdereference'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Sselect_hyperslab'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5T_NATIVE_INT_g'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Gclose'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Iinc_ref'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Awrite'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5open'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Dread'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Tcreate'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Gget_num_objs'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Tset_size'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5P_CLS_DATASET_CREATE_g'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5T_NATIVE_USHORT_g'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Dvlen_reclaim'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Tclose'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Fopen'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Pset_chunk'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Fclose'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE_g'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5T_NATIVE_ULLONG_g'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5Dcreate2'
//usr/local/lib/libmatio.so: undefined reference to `H5T_STD_REF_OBJ_g'
```

I tried many other codes to solve it:

```
g++ refine_pascal_v4/dense_inference.cpp -o prog_refine_pascal_v4 -W -Wall -O2 -L /usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/bin/glnxa64 -lDenseCRF -lmatio -I./util/ -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/bin/glnxa64


g++ refine_pascal_v4/dense_inference.cpp -o prog_refine_pascal_v4 -I /usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/extern/include -L /usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/bin/glnxa64 -leng -lmat -lmex -lut -W -Wall -O2 -L. -lDenseCRF -lmatio -I./util/ -Wl,-rpath, /usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/bin/glnxa64
```

not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling matio but that didnt do any help.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libhdf5-dev`

Comment: Yea tried that as well...it was already installed....so i uninstalled it and reinstalled it....did nothing

Comment: Install from source?

Comment: In middle of doing that I'm having some path issues with that

Comment: Did you get this to work? I'm also trying to get densecrf up and running and hitting this same error.

Comment: yes i added the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is to add an -lhdf5 after -lmatio:

```
g++ refine_pascal_v4/dense_inference.cpp util/Timer.h libDenseCRF.a
$(CC) refine_pascal_v4/dense_inference.cpp -o prog_refine_pascal_v4 $(CFLAGS) -L. -lDenseCRF -lmatio -lhdf5 -I./util/
```